# ArcGIS 10.3 not finding Python

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcgis-10.3

I just updated to ArcGIS 10.3, and lost the ability to use all of the tools that are dependent on python.  I do have "C:Python27>ArcGIS10.3>python.exe".  The Python27 folder also had the ArcGIS10.2 folder - I deleted it and restarted my comp to be sure it was gone in case Arc was looking in the wrong place.  Could someone provide instructions on how to tell Arc to recognize that Python is present?

Comment: What happens when you do `print sys.path`?

Comment: ['', u'c:\\program files (x86)\\arcgis\\desktop10.3\\arcpy', 'C:\\Python27\\ArcGIS10.2\\Lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python27.zip', 'C:\\Python27\\Lib', 'C:\\Python27\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python27\\Lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\Users\\Charles\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\2015_Data', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\ArcGIS\\Desktop10.3\\bin', 'C:\\Python27', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages']

Comment: I reinstalled Python, opened Arc, and ran 'print sys.path' in Python, through the geoprocessing menu.  But I still can't access Python dependent tools like Proximity @crmackey

Comment: Arc 10.3 uses Python 3.4, I believe. Looks like you're referencing Python 2.7. Do you have a Python 34 folder anywhere?

Comment: Arc 10.3 uses Python 2.7.8, so no need to involve any Python 3.x stuff. [Source](http://support.esri.com/fr/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/43889)

Comment: Your PYTHONPATH does not appear to be correct from an Esri perspective.  Everything should be referencing the 10.3 folder with the exception of the arcpy location, i.e. `C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\Lib\site-packages`.  Did you by chance install Python by itself at one point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had issues like this before in the past where IT had ran some automatic updates to look for outdated software, and it updated my Python by installing it stand alone from the internet. This broke everything similar to your case, but I was able to fix it by using this batch file (.bat) and **running it as an administrator** (won't work unless you do that).

```
setx -m PYTHONPATH "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\Lib\idlelib;C:\Windows\system32\python27.zip;C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\DLLs;C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\lib;C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\lib\plat-win;C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\lib\lib-tk;C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3;C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\lib\site-packages;C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\arcpy;C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\ArcToolbox\Scripts;
```

Also, if you have any folders/executables other than "ArcGIS10.3" in the `C:\Python27` directory, you will want to delete them so it only uses the ArcGIS Python install.

Comment: did you run that code in standalone python, or Arc?  Sorry, I'm not familiar with Python at all.

Comment: This is just a simple windows batch file, it runs from the command prompt.  Copy that text, save it in a text file with a `.bat` extension, and run it as an administrator.

Comment: As far as I know this worked.  The toolbox still doesn't have a description in the "search" menu, but I can access and use the tools.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you had PYTHONHOME or PYTHONPATH environmental variables set with your prior ArcGIS 10.x installation, they will not have been upgraded with the 10.x -> 10.3 upgrade. They need to point to the correct Python instance.

So, if they are set (necessary at times for Command window or PowerShell CLI) you will need to adjust them. Done from Computer -> Properties -> Advanced System Settings,  or in the Windows regsitry: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment